# Deleting an object within another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object

I'm trying to figure out whether or not this is possible. First off, I should say that I'm cloning the `FileReader` object and maintaining that throughout my application (so I can allow the user to remove files before they officially upload them).

All that works fine, but I'm hung up trying to figure out the best way to allow a user to remove a member from this cloned object (members are the same as files [images in my case] which would be found within a normal FileReader object).

So basically I've cloned the object, add a `pseudoHash` to it which allows me to reference the cloned member that the user wants to delete, and upon clicking on a "Remove" icon, I search for the associated `pseudoHash` which I've tied to that icon, within the cloned object, and delete the member. The would work fine if the object were in its own function, but it's not. So I'm having trouble trying to delete the object's members. I made `files` global in this case, but it's still not working.

```
        // Our FileList object
        files = e.target.files;
        // Create a clone since FileList is readonly
        files = cloneObject(files);
        // If files isn't empty, give the user the option to remove members
        if (files.length) {
            files = removeSelected(files);
        }
```

Here is my function. Unfortunately when I click to remove an image from the "upload queue", it should go through this function, but it actually doesn't delete the object, as I know Javascript doesn't ever completely delete objects, so if it's the last member, I try setting it to an empty object, but that doesn't work. If it's not the last member, I just want to remove it within its place. Again, because this is in a separate function and not the parent, it's only deleting the local reference to the variable.

```
   // Remove selected file from cloned fileList object
    var removeSelected = function(files) {
    var dataPseudoHash = $(this).attr('data-pseudo-hash');

        $('#js-selected-files').delegate('.js-remove-selected', 'click', function() {

            if (files.length == 1) {
                $('.js-image-upload').attr('disabled', true).addClass('btn_disabled');
                files = {};
                delete files;
            } else {
                // Loop through our files object and if we find a member with the same
                // pseudoHash as the attribute from whatever 'X' icon that was clicked, remove it
                $.each(files, function(i, dataPseudoHash) {
                    if (files[i].pseudoHash == dataPseudoHash) {
                        delete files[i];
                        files.length -= 1;
                    }
                });
            }

            // Remove hidden input that prevents duplicate files being uploaded of
            $('.js-pseudo-hash[value="' + dataPseudoHash + '"]').remove();

            $(this).parent().fadeOut('normal', function() {
                $(this).remove();
            });
        return files;
    };
```

What's the best way to handle this? Maybe setting a flag to true or false, and then delete the object or its members accordingly in the parent function depending on the case? Not quite sure. Other than that, I've got it uploading the files fine, but I need to find out how to remove properties of the object or the object altogether (if all "Remove" icons are clicked).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should know that the delete operator deletes only an element oof an array or element of an object not the whole array. In your first if condition

```
if (files.length == 1) {
            $('.js-image-upload').attr('disabled', true).addClass('btn_disabled');
            files = {};
            delete files;
}
```

You are deleting the whole object which returns false.
Now it will be better if you can manually check whether the second if condition is true or not in any case.